Prove P²=P for orthogonal projection formula
Given the following orthogonal projection formula $\hat{x}_w$ of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ on the vector $\frac{w}{\|w\|} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\hat{x}_w := \frac{c \cdot w}{\|w\|}$ where $c = \frac{x^T w}{\|w\|}$ we can define the following projection operator: $\hat{x}_w = P_w x$ i want to show that $P² = P$.
I tried to simply insert the values:
$P^2 = \frac{\hat{x}_w^T ww}{||w||^2}$ which seems promising but $ww \neq ||w||^2$ and $\hat{x}_w^T \neq \hat{x}_w$, what am i doing wrong?

You have to be careful because the $\cdot$ you use in your formula, which is the product of a scalar by a vector, is not the product of an $n\times k$ with a $k\times m$ matrix, and therefore you can't do things like comparing $(v^Tw)\cdot z$ with $v^T(wz)$ (which doesn't even make sense). If you want to see $\alpha\cdot x$ as that, you have to do $x\alpha$ if $x$ is column, and $\alpha x$ if $x$ is row.

Note that
$$P_{\mathbf w}(x)=\left(\frac{\mathbf x^{\top}\mathbf w}{\|\mathbf w\|}\right)\frac{\mathbf w}{\|\mathbf w\|}$$
Note that if $x$ is of the form $\lambda\mathbf w$, then
$$P_{\mathbf w}(\lambda\mathbf w)=\left(\frac{\lambda\mathbf w^{\top}\mathbf w}{\|\mathbf w\|}\right)\frac{\mathbf w}{\|\mathbf w\|}$$
But $\mathbf w^\top\mathbf w=\|\mathbf w\|^2$, so
$$P_{\mathbf w}(\lambda\mathbf w)=\lambda\mathbf w$$
(Can you think of an intuitive reason why the above must be true? Think what $P_{\mathbf w}$ means!)
Now, note that for any $\mathbf x$, the vector $P_{\mathbf w}(\mathbf x)$ is of the form $\lambda\mathbf x$, so
$$P_\mathbf{w}(P_{\mathbf w}(x))=P_\mathbf{w}(\lambda\mathbf x)=\lambda\mathbf x=P_{\mathbf w}(x)$$
and so you are done.
Hope this helps. :)
